# Order by numeric component of value range in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This scenario:

```
create table #scores (score int)

insert into #scores values (1)
insert into #scores values (1)
insert into #scores values (2)
insert into #scores values (3)
insert into #scores values (7)
insert into #scores values (14)
insert into #scores values (14)

;WITH Ranges AS
(
    SELECT *
    ,CASE 
        WHEN score between 1 and 5
            THEN '1-5'
        WHEN score between 6 and 10
            THEN '6-10'
        WHEN score between 11 and 15
            THEN '11-15'
        END AS ScoreRange
    FROM #scores
)
SELECT Count = COUNT(*), ScoreRange
FROM Ranges 
GROUP BY ScoreRange
ORDER BY ScoreRange
```

Results in this data:

```
Count   ScoreRange
2       11-15
4       1-9
1       6-10
```

Is there a simple way I can get the data sorted by ScoreRange as though it's a numeric rather than a string? So 1-5 comes first, then 6-10, then 11-15 and so on?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't change 1-5 to 01-05, and 6-10 to 06-10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why Not

**`ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(ScoreRange, 0, charindex('-', ScoreRange, 0)) AS INT)`**

Try this

```
;WITH Ranges AS
(
    SELECT *
    ,CASE 
        WHEN score between 1 and 5
            THEN '1-5'
        WHEN score between 6 and 10
            THEN '6-10'
        WHEN score between 11 and 15
            THEN '11-15'
        END AS ScoreRange
    FROM #scores
)
SELECT Count = COUNT(*), ScoreRange
FROM Ranges 
GROUP BY ScoreRange
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(ScoreRange, 0, charindex('-', ScoreRange, 0)) AS INT)
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/36764)**

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to do it in a similar manner by dissecting the string and casting to INT, but I couldn't figure out the correct logic.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I do in cases like this. Very useful for when you want to output data in the way you are wanting, I personally use it for report output or for grids which don't have any sorting ability.

```
;WITH Ranges AS
(
    SELECT *
    ,CASE 
        WHEN score between 1 and 5
            THEN '1-5'
        WHEN score between 6 and 10
            THEN '6-10'
        WHEN score between 11 and 15
            THEN '11-15'
        END AS ScoreRange
    FROM #scores
)
SELECT Count = COUNT(*), ScoreRange
FROM Ranges 
GROUP BY ScoreRange
ORDER BY LEN(ScoreRange),
         ScoreRange
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is simply:

```
ORDER BY MIN(score)
```

That is, choose an arbitrary score from the range and order by that.

Answer (score 1):

Because `ScoreRange` is a string, we can expect string/word sorting instead of numeric sorting.

In this form of sorting, numbers come before letters and characters, so `11` comes before `1-` and `6-`, and `1-` comes before `6-`.

This gives us:

```
11-15
1-5
6-10
```

If the `ScoreRange` values were instead zero-prefixed `(1-5 -> 01-05)` the sorting changes.

Using the same string/word sorting `01-` comes before `05-`, and `05-` comes before `10-`.

The semantic meaning of the numbers (`1` is before `5`, which is before `10`) is retained, but this now works under string/word comparison.

This approach works for all values up to `99`; add an extra zero if your max value goes higher:

```
001-005
006-010
011-015
016-100
101-999
```

Your query now becomes:

```
;WITH Ranges AS
(
     SELECT *,
            CASE 
                 WHEN score between 1 and 5 THEN '01-05'
                 WHEN score between 6 and 10 THEN '06-10'
                 WHEN score between 11 and 15 THEN '11-15'
            END AS ScoreRange
       FROM #scores
)
SELECT Count = COUNT(*), ScoreRange
  FROM Ranges 
 GROUP BY ScoreRange
 ORDER BY ScoreRange
```

See my SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f0699/2/0

Comment: In my particular case I have to match pre-existing ranges from an external source, so I can't use this. But +1 for a thorough, well-explained and useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
;WITH Ranges AS
(
    SELECT *
    ,CASE 
        WHEN score between 1 and 5
            THEN '1-5'
        WHEN score between 6 and 10
            THEN '6-10'
        WHEN score between 11 and 15
            THEN '11-15'
        END AS ScoreRange
    FROM #scores
)
SELECT Count = COUNT(*), ScoreRange
FROM Ranges 
GROUP BY ScoreRange
ORDER BY CASE ScoreRange 
                WHEN '1-5' THEN 1 
                WHEN '6-10' THEN 2
                ELSE 3
        END
```

Comment: Since there's already a case statement in the `CTE`, it would make sense to include the ordering case statement in there too and have the main select a bit cleaner, and all the code to handle groups close together.